# React - Use Memo not preventing re-render of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within my app, I have an object stored in state, which stores a bunch of message objects. I use a hook to retrieve the data within the `Chat` Component. I map over the data, and display it like so:

```
 {Object.keys(storedUsers).length !== 0  && chatId && Object.keys(chatMessages).length !== 0  && Object.values(chatMessages).map((messageObj, index) => {
               return <ChatMessage key={index} messageObj={messageObj} />
     })}
```

Within **ChatMessage**, I have a message object which I display the data for. This is the **ChatMessageComponent**:

```
const ChatMessage = ({messageObj}) => { 
        // MEMOIZED VALUE
        const newMessageObj = useMemo(() => {return messageObj})

        if (messageObj.admin === true) return 

   
        const sentById = newMessageObj.sentBy
        let sentByUser
        let isOwn

        if (sentById === userData.userId) {
         sentByUser = userData
         isOwn = true
        }
        else {
         sentByUser = storedUsers &&  storedUsers[sentById] ||  newChatData  && newChatData.otherUsersData
        }



        return ( 
            <div className='d-flex flex-row' style={{marginTop: 50}}>

                // VIDEO COMPONENT
                <Video messageObject={newMessageObj} />

             </div>
)
```

I have a `<Video />` component within this component, which I only want to render on mount, or if the Message Url changes.

**Video component:**

```
import React, { memo, useEffect } from 'react'


const Video = memo(({messageObject}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('RE-RENDERED');
    }, [])

  return (
    <video>
        <source src={messageObject.url} />
    </video>
  )
},)

export default Video
```

However, when unrelated state in the `ChatMessages` component changes, the child `Video component` is re-rendered. I am memoizing the message object that is being passed into the `Video` component as a prop. How can I ensure the Video component doesn't re-render unless neccessary? Is there anything missing which is causing the component to Re-render? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Selector to retrieve ChatMessages:

```
const chatMessages = useSelector((state) => state.messages.messagesData[chatId]) || {}
```

Comment: sup' with the key with the random number?

Comment: @terpinmd Please check my updated code. I have replaced the keys with random values, however the re-render of the **Video** component is still occuring

Comment: @terpinmd Could the problem be that I am not memoizing `newMessageObj` correctly, and that is causing the re-render?

Answer (score 0):

React component `key`s need to be stable. Using `Math.random` as a key is an anti-pattern frequently seen, but it's actually the worst of several options you have to create a key. This is likely the root cause of your issue with memoization.

The tip off is your console log:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('RE-RENDERED');
}, [])
```

This console log will *not* fire on re-render like the message implies, but will only fire when the component is first mounted. Since you are seeing this fire on "render", what it actually means is that the component is being unmounted and re-mounted each time the parent renders.

This is exactly what will happen when a component's `key` changes. The `key` tells react which instance of the component you're referring to. If it sees the same key, it knows it's the same instance - so re-render it. If it sees a different key, it knows it's a *new* component - so it destroys the old one and creates a new instance.

To fix your problem, find a suitable unique, stable value. That may be something within the `messageObj`, or at worst case the `index` of the array item.

```
.map((messageObj, index) => {
  // Ideally use something from the messageObj, but the index works in a pinch
  return <ChatMessage key={index} messageObj={messageObj} />
})}
```

The big takeaway here is to **never** use `Math.random` as a piece of a `key`. I've seen it too often in code here and other places online because it quickly gets rid of the warning in the console, but it's much worse than just using the array index.

Comment: Index is not a good key too (perhaps multiple maps). The best way is to have a unique id for each message. then pass `key={message.id}`

Comment: My answer addresses this twice. I don't know what's inside of the message object, and I don't know if the array actually has a potential to change over time (the reason why using the array index can be harmful). The answer addresses the root problem the OP is facing and provides guidance to correct it in an appropriate way

Comment: @BrianThompson Hello, I have updated my code accordingly, however the component is continuing to re-render. I know this due to the **console.log** in the video component

Comment: The console.log isn't causing a re-render, and the useEffect doesn't run on re-render. It runs on component mount. If you are still seeing that log more often then you should, you still have a `key` bug. Are you doing the same thing at a higher level?

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes, the console log is running because of the re-render. However I have changed the key accordingly, and there are no more related keys. Could the problem be on the line where I call `useMemo` to create a new object from the exisiting object?

Comment: @BrianThompson Please see my update. This is the selector I use in order to retrieve the chatMessages. This object is recreated on every re-render, therefore could that be the problem? If so, how could I memoize **chatMessages**?

Comment: Misconfigured memoization will not cause components to unmount and remount, so this is not the problem